# How to assign the dynamic value instead of 1800 on this tag?

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic

How to assign the dynamic value instead of 1800 on this tag?

```
<div class="timer" data-seconds-left="1800"></div>
```

Comment: What dynamic value? Do you mean to set the attribute value with JavaScript?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can set an attribute.
Add your method to make it dynamic.

```
function set_the_value(){
var value="";
document.getElementsByClassName("timer").setAttribute("data-second-left", value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("#timer").attr('data-seconds-left', 1200);
```

or

if you use newer jQuery >= 1.4.3,

```
  $("#timer").data("seconds-left", 1200);
```

also  make sure your attribute contains only lower case letters.